# How do I use repetition in macro_rules without a metavariable?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a `macro_rules` definition that makes it easy to define types in a custom programming language.

Here's what I've got so far:

```rust
macro_rules! ty {
    (_ []) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Array(TypeArray { .. })
    };
    ($inner: tt []) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Array($crate::types::expr::TypeArray {
            item: Box::new(ty!($inner)),
        })
    };
    (int) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Primitive($crate::types::expr::TypePrimitive::Int)
    };
    (bool) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Primitive($crate::types::expr::TypePrimitive::Bool)
    };
    (*) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Any
    };
    (()) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Unit
    };
    ( { $e: expr } ) => {
        $e
    };
}
```

This works fine if I write `int` or `int[]`, but breaks if I write `int[][]`. I tried to add a branch like this:

```rust
    ($inner: tt $([])+) => {
        $crate::types::expr::Type::Array($crate::types::expr::TypeArray {
            item: Box::new(ty!($inner)),
        })
    };
```

But I don't know how to get recursive repetition using the `[]` because there's no metavariable associated with it. What do I do?

Comment: Just heads up: if you want a macro parser powerfull enough to model a custom programming language, you might want to use proc-macros instead.

Comment: Also: can't reproduce because `crate::types` does not exist. Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: What do you need the output to be?